# What was the soundtrack with Juuzou looking at Big Madam during the auction raid in Tokyo Ghoul Re:?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

So there's a soundtrack on episode 4 of Tokyo Ghoul Re: at around 10:07, during the auction raid, Juuzou looks at Big Madame and this OST plays. Could someone identify and show me a link to the music used?

Answer (score -1):

Most likely an instrumental version of [Tokyo Ghoul:re OST - Willpower (Feat. Future Sunsets) By Yutaka Yamada](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R85p6IyAVW8)